# ColdFusion - What is the best way to replace values to format a paragraph?

Tags: coldfusion, user-defined-functions, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9.

I am outputting a chunk of text from a database to be directly into a web page. I don't want users to have to write HTML and screw things up. So, I am having them insert a double at sign "@@" to denote a new paragraph.  Data is stored like this:

```
 @@This is my first paragraph. @@This will be my second paragraph. @@This is my third.
```

What I want to do is create a function that will turn the above block of text into the block of text below:

```
 <p>This is my first paragraph.</p>
 <p>This will be my second paragraph.</p>
 <p>This is my third.</p>
```

I will never know whether the user actually used any @@ signs or not.  If they didn't, I'll need to wrap the entire block in a p tag.

My first thought is to do this:

1. Wrap the entire block into a p tag.
2. Replace the first occurrence of @@ with "" (nothing).
3. Replace every other occurrence of @@ with `</p><p>`

Is this the right way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: you're asking your user to type `@@` instead of `<p>`? How about just a textarea and you can replace `\n\n` with `<p>` with `ParagraphFormat()`

Comment: and btw, `</p>` is optional in HTML 4.01

Comment: in addition to all the suggestions on how to achieve this you will also need to sanitise the output so `scripts` don't auto run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`REReplace(your text, "@@([^@]+)", "<p>\1</p>", "all");`

should sort it!

Answer (score 2):

If you are committed to avoiding HTML (which isn't such a bad idea), and you'd rather not use Henry's idea of a textarea and `ParagraphFormat()`, what I'd recommend is using '@@' to represent a paragraph **break**. There's no need to prefix text with it, because they're always going to have at least one paragraph of text, right? (And if they enter nothing at all, you don't need any paragraphs.)

Aside from that, yes, simply replacing `@@` with `</p><p>` or simply `<p>` is fine ... if you don't need them to start the text with it, then your replacement process is easier, because you can skip step 2, and if you can use just `<p>` without closing it, then you can skip step 1 as well. (If you were trying to create XHTML, then you'd need to use closing tags, but then you'd have a more difficult task handling the text for each paragraph ...)

Comment: I din't like the idea of not being well formed. All tags need to have closing tags. In my opinion, paragraphFormat(), is a weak tag. It doesn't do what it really needs to do. It really shouldn't exist. It's one of the first tags a CFer should lose.

Comment: That's perfectly reasonable; so either your approach or Ken's would work and be fairly simple to implement. (Users entering HTML tags themselves, well-formed or not, would be an issue no matter what solution you implement, so it's no less important to plan for that with your solution than it would be with Sean's.)

Comment: My question is about the best way to parse the code block. My question is not about other means of collecting and cleaning a block of code before it gets to the database. I am sorry if that wasn't clear. Absolutely no HTML will be stored.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
testParagraph = '@@First graf. @@Second graf. @@Third graf.';
arPara = testParagraph.split('@@');
for( i = 2; i <= arrayLen(arPara); i++ ){ // start at 2 to avoid blank graf
  writeoutput('<p>' & arPara[i] & '</p>');
}
```

Comment: I'd still recommend dropping that first @@. `split` is a good approach, though.

Answer (score 2):

I like Ken's approach of splitting on '@@'.  However, I wouldn't simply start from the second array item.  Users might not realize they need to put @@ before the first paragraph, or they might think they need to put it after the last one.  I would split it, then test each paragraph to make sure it's not empty.  If the users enter it right, the first one will be empty and not show.  If they don't, no foul.

```
testParagraph = '@@First graf. @@Second graf. @@Third graf.';
arPara = testParagraph.split('@@');
for( i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arPara); i++ ){ // start at 2 to avoid blank graf
  if (trim(arPara[i]) neq "") writeoutput('<p>' & arPara[i] & '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um why not use TinyMCE [or something similar] for the text area tht the users need to edit, that way the editor will generate all the html for you and users neither have to use your @@ or insert html?

You can then still sanitize the user input before committing to the DB just incase you are worried about nefarious HTML ....

-sean

**UPDATE**

ok - well then how about using the list to array function, testing your first array element to be sure it's not empty, then just loop over the array with the '

' in the appropriate place? The delimiters param of listToArray effectively strips out your "@@" - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_21.html

Comment: Um, because normal users usually make stuff look pretty stupid. Check out the difference between MySpace and Facebook.

Comment: The answer to that is very simple - strip out any html but the P tags and other basic formatting that won't interfere with your design guide. You can configure TinyMCE to not provide most of the formatting buttons and, if you want to take it one step further, you can link a specific style sheet to the format options & only give your users the option to use styles and presentation that you have defined in that style sheet.  Yes you still will have to sanitize and validate for some html, but that is pretty straight forward with CF.

Comment: My question is about the best way to parse the code block. My question is not about other means of collecting and cleaning a block of code before it gets to the database. I am sorry if that wasn't clear. Absolutely no HTML will be stored.

Comment: ok - well then how about using the list to array function, testing your first array element to be sure it's not empty, then just loop over the array with the '</p><p>' in the appropriate place? The delimiters param of listToArray effectively strips out your "@@" - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_21.html

Comment: Sean, your last solution is almost perfect.  Another user offered the use of MyParagraph.split('@@'); I had never heard of split() before. Basically, in case you don't know, it's breaks a string directly into an array. In this case, each time it sees @@, it puts whatever follow into new element of the array.  Maybe this is what you meant. Either way, thanks!

Comment: No problem...  I've seen the split before, but never fully looked into it, I ~think~ it's new for cfscript under CF9 - but don't quote me on that. [could be java too I suppose...]

Answer (score 0):

I think people are suggesting different approaches to dealing with the data is because your approach is unnecessarily... err... "less than ideal".  You are asking "question x", but people can see the flaw in the premise of "question x", hence offering better suggestions to address the seemingly flawed premise that was the basis of "question x".  I think their approach is sound, and as a newbie (judging on the questions you ask here, I mean), it might be worthwhile being a little bit more open to people offering advice: they are not doing it for no reason, after all!

I agree with the people suggesting you revise your approach, btw.

However, to answer your question, do this:

- s = reReplace(s, "^\s*@@(.*)$", "

  \1

  ", "ONE")
- replace all instances of @@ with

That's it.  There is nothing complex here.

A better answer to the *situation* - if not the question - would be to look at how web-based text editors like TinyMCE can be fine-tuned to allow some mark-up, but not others.  Like it or not, this would be a better approach to your situation.

Comment: Funny, half the people will vote down a question for not being specific enough and the other half will vote it answers that aren't specific enough. I asked a specific question to accomplish a specific task. There are a hundred reasons I need to approach the task the way I did, none of which I cited. I might have taken my approach because my boss said "do not use TinyMCE". And you want me to spend my time considering that approach when it's completely irrelevant?  Really? How you you say it's "less than ideal" when you have no clue as to what my restrictions and environment are?

Comment: You sound like a completely arrogant know-it-all. Many times, I ask questions because I want to get at alternatives. Sometimes I ask for a different approach. Sometimes I request that responses be exceedingly limited in scope. Your answers need to serve my questions.  If you don't like my questions, don't answer them. If you don't like my approach, fine.  But to think you know much about me solely by the questions I ask, you don't much about anything.

Comment: Furthermore... If asked for directions to the local market, I am NOT looking for suggestions on restaurants or coffee shops or pubs to go to. You need to assume that I need to get to a specific local market for a specific reason that I have not cited.  Any assumptions on your part are shots in the dark.

Comment: Evik: chill out. You •specifically asked• if yours was the best approach. It's not our fault if we (all) think the answer is "no". Expecting users to put in special sequences of characters to denote para breaks where there are more professional ways to do it is suboptimal. Note: my answer before was slightly wrong, and I've updated it. This stemmed from you having a LEADING para break in there, which I didn't notice. It seems wrong to me to have a para break mark at the BEGINNING of some text, btw.